# GARCH(2,1) interpretation

Tags: interpretation, garch

I have a GARCH(2,1) model that mitigates heteroscedasticity, i.e. no ARCH effects.
I use GARCH(2,1) because GARCH(1,1) didn't mitigate heteroscedasticity.

Below I will give the values of the ARCH & GARCH terms for 2 different models.

Example 1: (1st ARCH term is not significant)

```
Resid(-1)^2  =  0.0300     (not significant)
Resid(-1)^2  =  0.04200
GARCH(-1)    =  0.89400
```

How do I interpret example 1, and do I include `Resid(-1)^2` in the variance equation even when it's not significant?

Example 2: (all are significant)

```
Resid(-1)^2  =  0.15300
Resid(-1)^2  = -0.07200
GARCH(-1)    =  0.87400
```

How do I interpret the negative value of `Resid(-1)^2`, is it there because ARCH + GARCH terms must be < 1?